# Generic Return Type in Java

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, abstract-class, java-7

I'm implementing a method on an abstract class which returns a list of concrete types depending on what parameter it receives.

```
public static List<T extends AbstractClass> method(List<? extends AbstractClass> objects) {
    return listOfT;
}
```

The method above lives on the abstract class. If I call it with a list of ConcreteType1 then I get back a `List<ConcreteType1>`. If I call it with ConcreteType2, then I get back a `List<ConcreteType1>`.

As it's written it doesn't work right now. I get a compilation error that says "Unexpected Bound". Any ideas?

Comment: You've forgotten to declare your type parameter. The bounds would be declared with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be written

```
public static <T extends AbstractClass> List<T> method(List<T> objects) {
    return listOfT;
}
```